# Node - Node-HID not finding device

Tags: node.js, barcode-scanner, hid, motorola

I am trying to create an Angular and Node program that utilizes a barcode scanner. I am building on a mac and I am using a Motorola DS9208 scanner which can read both qr codes and barcodes. When I `console.log(devices)` all of the devices are made by Apple except this one, which does not provide much information:

```
{ 
    vendorId: 0,
    productId: 0,
    path: 'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SBUS@1F,3/AppleSMBusPCI/BUS0@0/AppleSMBusControllerICH/MKY0/AppleMikeyDriver/AppleMikeyHIDDriver',
    serialNumber: '',
    manufacturer: '',
    product: 'Apple Mikey HID Driver',
    release: 0,
    interface: -1,
    usagePage: 12,
    usage: 1 
}
```

It is the only USB device plugged in so I assume that it is the HID it is referring to. However, My problem is when I try to actually scan things. When I set `var device = new HID.HID(0,0)` since the vendor and product IDs are 0, and use function

`device.on('data', function(data) { console.log(data)} )`

nothing happens. Same when I do the same for checking errors. When the scanner scans any barcode it beeps once then beeps four more times with red lights giving off some sort of error message. Can anyone help me out? Thank you